# Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Application MVVM Login

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, rest, mvvm

I'm creating a Login View which will ask the user for their username and password and then the user can click the Login button to try and login. When the user clicks the button in the click handler for that button i call the Login() method on my LoginViewModel class with the username and password which is validated in that method and then the method makes an async REST request to my web service with the username and password. Once the username and password are validated on the web service and the service returns true to say that these credentials are valid how do i notify the Login View so that the Login View can stop showing the progress dialog and show a different page or display an error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an mvvm framework to implement mvvm but it speeds things up.  In mvvm light you can have a RootView that has a navigation frame and use the messenger to tell the RootView to swap in or out the LoginView or the MainView based on authentication.

For wp7 apps I prefer [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Windows%20Phone%207%20v1.1&referringTitle=Documentation) because it does a lot of work for you like making it easy to navigate pages in the forced View first approach but then makes using the ViewModel first approach on sub pages easy as well.  CM also has some nice things built in to help you handle tombstoning.

In CM your ShellView can have a ContentControl and you can Activate LoginViewModel or MainViewModel bases on authentication passing or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a boolean property in your viewmodel that says if the viewmodel is busy or not. Then you would bind that property to the IsOpen property of the popup.
For the navigation part there are several options. One of them is to have a controller that knows how to go from page to page, and it's used by the viewmodel.

Also, why are you passing parameters to your login method? And why are you using events in the first place? You should consider creating a command in your vm and binding it directly to the button.

You need a MVVM framework to follow this pattern on Windows Phone. I would recommend [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) or [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).